# Doctrine multiple inheritance entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, discriminator

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "element" = "Element",
 *     "comment" = "ElementComment",
 *     "question" = "ElementQuestion"
 * })
 */
class Element {

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "question" = "ElementQuestion"
 *     "range" = "ElementQuestionRange",
 *     "text" = "ElementQuestionText",
 * })
 */
class ElementQuestion {

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ElementQuestionRange {

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ElementQuestionText {

}
```

Normally i should have informations about child class in discr column in main class.

But if it is multilevel inheritance symfony still adding informations about third level class in first level class and doesn't create discr column in second level class.

I can find third level collection, second level collection, but if I want find first level it doesn't work, because discr is invalid for it.

Should I add all second and third level classes to @ORM/DiscriminatorMap in main class or can I do it better?